# Stuck in Game Center Sandbox?

Tags: ios, center, simulator

I have a problem with Game Center. I registered a user for Game Center in the Simulator during the time GC was still in beta. 
When the beta ended however, I wasn't able to use that Apple ID in the real Game Center. GC just keeps telling me the account has already been registered and offers me to create a new Game Center account that's tied to my Apple ID.
Am I stuck and need to register a whole new account? Or can I somehow reuse my sandbox account?

Regards,
Andreas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Developer Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/GameCenterOverview/GameCenterOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008304-CH5-SW7) of Game Center states that you have to create one account for the Sandbox and one account for the normal Game Center.
So, I guess, you have to create a whole new Apple ID for your normal Game Center.